# Can my Linux box turn off the UPS after it shuts down?

Tags: linux, unix, ups

I have an APC UPS with all my computer peripherals plugged into it. When I'm done using the computer, I'd like to be able to type "shutdown" or "init 0" and walk away from the machine, trusting that it will shut down cleanly and then signal the UPS to shut off power to all peripherals.

I understand that there is a "kill the power" signal that APC UPSes can be sent, and I have that working in the event of a power failure: apcupsd will shut down the computer and, at the last moment, tell the UPS to turn off. But this only works when running on battery.

When it gets that killpower signal while running on AC power, the UPS turns off for a few seconds, and then it turns right back on automatically. Is this expected behavior? Can it be disabled, so that the UPS stays off, even when there is AC power?

Answer (score 2):

try [nut](http://eu1.networkupstools.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, perhaps not quite what you asked for, but this is the hardware solution that I use at home:
http://www.oneclickpower.com/store/

Plug all the peripherals into this, and they'll turn off when your pc powers down. Keep your ups plugged into the mains obviously.

Answer (score 0):

If the computers are connected via network, your could also think about an other solution. Like sending shutdown command via ssh or so. I have done it this way, with 3 mac systems.

Comment: This is about signaling to UPS to turn off a single machine (with peripherals) once the machine shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

The apcupsd on my SuSE box knows the `--power-off` switch wich will do exactly that. It may require the "smart" protocol, so it may not work on the simpler "Back"-UPS.